# transformation of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I have this D.E:
$$y^{''}+P(x)y^{'}+Q(x)y=0$$
which transformation $y \to u(x)$, shall I take to transform the D.E to: $u^{''}+q(x)u=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. Let $y=\rho(x)u(x)$ and then put it in the equation to get
$$ \rho''(x)u(x)+2\rho'(x)u'(x)+\rho(x)u''(x)+P(x)(\rho'(x)u(x)+\rho(x)u'(x))+Q(x)\rho(x)u(x)=0. \tag1 $$
Write (1) as an equation of $u$:
$$ \rho(x)u''(x)+(2\rho'(x)+P(x)\rho(x))u'(x)+(\rho''(x)u(x)+P(x)\rho'(x)+Q(x)\rho(x))u(x)=0. \tag2$$
Letting
$$ 2\rho'(x)+P(x)\rho(x)=0 $$
which implies
$$ \rho(x)=\exp\bigg(-\frac12\int P(x)dx\bigg) $$
and then dividing both sides of (2) by $\rho(x)$, one has
$$ u''(x)+q(x)u(x)=0 $$
for some $q(x)$ depending on $P(x),Q(x)$.

Comment: yup, thanks!!!!